# PVC created with no accessmode and storage class

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc, kubernetes-statefulset

I am using the following yaml to deploy Keydb into my cluster

```
---
# Source: keydb/templates/cm-utils.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: keydb-utils
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: keydb-0.8.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: keydb
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: keydb
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "5.3.3"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
data:
  server.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash
    set -euxo pipefail

    host="$(hostname)"
    port="6379"
    replicas=()
    for node in {0..2}; do
      if [ "$host" != "keydb-${node}" ]; then
          replicas+=("--replicaof keydb-${node}.keydb ${port}")
      fi
    done
    keydb-server /etc/keydb/redis.conf \
        --active-replica yes \
        --multi-master yes \
        --appendonly no \
        --bind 0.0.0.0 \
        --port "$port" \
        --protected-mode no \
        --server-threads 2 \
        "${replicas[@]}"
---
# Source: keydb/templates/svc.yaml
# Headless service for proper name resolution
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keydb
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: keydb-0.8.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: keydb
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: keydb
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "5.3.3"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: server
    port: 6379
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: keydb
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: keydb
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: keydb
---
# Source: keydb/templates/sts.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: keydb
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: keydb-0.8.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: keydb
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: keydb
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "5.3.3"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 3
  serviceName: keydb
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: keydb
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: keydb
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/cm-utils: e0806d2d0698a10e54131bde1119e44c51842191a777c154c308eab52ebb2ec7
      labels:
        helm.sh/chart: keydb-0.8.0
        app.kubernetes.io/name: keydb
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: keydb
        app.kubernetes.io/version: "5.3.3"
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - keydb
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      containers:
      - name: keydb
        image: eqalpha/keydb:x86_64_v5.3.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command:
        - /utils/server.sh
        ports:
        - name: keydb
          containerPort: 6379
          protocol: TCP
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: keydb
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: keydb
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 2Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 1Gi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: keydb-data
          mountPath: /data
        - name: utils
          mountPath: /utils
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: utils
        configMap:
          name: keydb-utils
          defaultMode: 0700
          items:
          - key: server.sh
            path: server.sh
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: keydb-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 2Gi
      storageClassName: "gp2"
```

using the command

```
kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml
```

There is no error while creation

```
$ kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml
configmap/keydb-utils created
service/keydb created
statefulset.apps/keydb created
```

But the pod is not getting scheduled with the following error

```
 status:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  conditions:                                                                                                                                                                                            
  - lastProbeTime: null                                                                                                                                                                                  
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-04-24T15:44:39Z"                                                                                                                                                           
    message: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 3 times)                                                                                                                         
    reason: Unschedulable                                                                                                                                                                                
    status: "False"                                                                                                                                                                                      
    type: PodScheduled                                                                                                                                                                                   
  phase: Pending                                                                                                                                                                                         
  qosClass: Burstable
```

When I check the PVC, its created with no access modes or storage class.

```
$ kubectl get  pvc
NAME                 STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
keydb-data-keydb-0   Pending                                                     28m
```

Please help.

Added Storage class output

```
$ kubectl get sc
NAME            PROVISIONER                    AGE
gp2 (default)   kubernetes.io/aws-ebs          32d
local-storage   kubernetes.io/no-provisioner   10h
```

No PV are created for this.

Comment: can you please run ```kubectl get sc`` and check if storageclass is exists? also run ```kubectl get pv``` to check any pv created or not

Comment: @hoque added the details

Comment: In gp2 storageclass, is there ```zones: <>```  present or not? you can check that by running ```kubectl get sc gp2 -o yaml```

Comment: I am running 16 more services using gp2 and all of them are working fine. There is problem with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheduling errors can often occur when affinity conditions are not met. Should you be using pod affinity rather than antiaffinity? Or even node affinity instead? Maybe try schedule with node affinity, or simpler affinity rules to try rule out affinity as a cause first.

See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) for examples on affinity.